# Allow locking of answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, locked

Locking of questions is currently in place, and is typically used in cases like halting edit wars. However, instead of locking an entire question and its answers, I think that it would also be beneficial to able to lock *individual answers*, leaving the question and other answers still active.

Some reasons why I think it would be useful:

- **If an answer falls prey to an edit war:** Admittedly, I haven't actually seen this happen for an *answer*, just questions. But locking only the answer would be a helpful option in such a case.
- **For specific use on MetaSO:** There are a number of questions on MetaSO that have the form where the question is simply a container for a general class of feature request, with the answers representing the specific individual feature requests that are accepted or declined. For example, [The Great Tagging Reorg](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/the-great-tagging-reorg). Some of the retagging suggestions in the answers have been completed, and these are indicated with a "DONE" icon placed at the top (example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/the-great-tagging-reorg/2856#2856)). However, the answer can still be edited, voted on, and commented on, which isn't really of any use now that the request has been filled. The answer *could* be deleted, but then there's no record of previously suggested and accepted requests. It would be nicer if the answer alone could be locked, freezing the editing, voting, and commenting so that it can simply remain there for posterity.

So, what's the community's take? Is this a useful/feasible feature request?

---

**EDIT:** As Kyle so adeptly pointed out with his answer, this feature is already enabled. In short, you pretty much can't do *anything* to a locked answer... unless you're a mod, in which case you can unlock it.

As a summary, here's what you can't do to locked answers:

- Edit
- Up/downvote
- <strike>Flag</strike>
- Mark as accepted (I was kinda surprised by this one)
- Comment
- Upvote comments
- Flag comments

Comment: Hmmm - pity you can't comment on locked answers :(

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing!

Comment: Well, I guess I'll comment here since Kyle's answer below is locked =P ... it's nice to know this feature already exists. It should be useful for the "bulk request" questions here on MetaSO.

Comment: It would be nice if moderators could be more precise in what they disable when locking a post. For example, a runaway comment thread and a rollback war are different things, but locking is the only tool that will solve either.

Comment: Looks like you can't vote on or flag the comments on the locked answer either - thanks Tom Ritter for proving that!

Comment: I just found out that you can't select a locked answer as the accepted answer either. Poor Kyle, no +15 for you. ;)

Comment: Tell you what - I'll *temporarily* unlock it so we can bring, uh, *closure* to the question.

Comment: any idea why you can't comment on locked answers but you can comment on locked questions?

Comment: I didn't think you *could* comment on locked questions.

Comment: @gnovice: Yes, you can - just try it!

Comment: "If an answer falls prey to an edit war" Oh thats good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, moderators *are* capable of locking individual answers. If think an answer (or question, for that matter) should be locked, flag it for moderator attention with a short reason of why it should be locked. If the moderator agrees they will lock it for you.

(This answer has been locked as a demonstration)

Comment: And of course, we can unlock too ;)