# What abilities are moderators given?

Tags: discussion, moderator-abilities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are diamond moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/what-are-diamond-moderators)

Out of curiosity, is there a list somewhere of all the abilities that moderators have? For instance, I just found out [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3781/feature-request-locking-answers) that mods can lock answers.  I remember seeing a couple of times that there are some limitations on what mods can do (mostly due to the underlying engine), so I was just wondering, exactly what abilities do the mods have?