# Don't know which OpenId I used

Tags: support, status-completed, openid

I'm trying to log into SO after a hiatus of a few months. Unfortunately, I've no idea which OpenID I used to sign myself up.

I've got various email accounts with associated OpenIDs, plus one I run on my personal domain; but I've tried all the ones I can think of, and none of them seem to be the right one.

Is there some way I can retrieve my account, or find out which openid is associated with it?

Answer (score 1):

I have found your account; I will e-mail details to the e-mail address listed (done).

Answer (score 0):

Send an email to team@stackoverflow.com with whatever information you can remember. Like what username you had here etc.

Comment: I wonder whether SO needs a "email me my openid" button for exactly the same reason that other sites need a "email me my password" button.

Comment: Seriously people, "email to team" isn't the only answer to everything... in particular, e-mails don't automatically go to the ♦ mods, so things can often be answered more quickly here.

Comment: OpenId needs to be entered in correct format too, I think. <pre>http://YourName.openid.com/

Comment: A list of what the ♦ mods can do would be helpful.

Comment: @Ólafur Waage, the mods can disconnect themselves from the Matrix whenever they want and go to the real world, the rest of us can't.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3783/moderator-abilities

Comment: Thank you for the update.