# What is the difference between "merged" questions and "closed (exact duplicate)" questions?

Tags: support, closed-questions, merged-questions

While looking at [What abilities are moderators given?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3783/164291) I noticed that the question has been merged:

[image: merged by Robert Harvey ♦ Aug 25 at 23:02]

What is the difference between a merged question, and one that has been closed as a duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the text of a Closed as Duplicate post ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348600/removing-duplicate-in-table)) it says:

> This question covers exactly the same ground as earlier questions on
>   this topic; its **answers may be merged** with another identical question.
>   See the FAQ.

When questions are merged the answers from both questions are placed into the original question. 
This will be handy when someone provides a good answer to a duplicate question. After a merge there will only be one question with all the answers, thus making it easier to search and get answers. Also, the answers won't be part of a closed question any more.

Comment: The question that was merged into another one is also implicitly locked and no further voting or leaving comments is possible on it. The remaining "stub" will eventually be deleted and the URL that pointed to the merged question will redirect to the combined version.